# R : import millions of small alpha numeric csv files

Tags: r

I have about 300GB of 15KB csv files (each with exactly 100 rows each) that I need to import, concatenate, manipulate and resave as a single rds.

I've managed to reduce the amount of RAM needed by only importing the columns I need but as soon as I need to do any operations on the columns, I max it out.

What is your strategy for this type of problem?

Comment: Do you really need all data at once to perform the operation? If so one option would be to pump it all into a DB and preprocess as much as possible when storing it in the DB - then perform the final calculations there. If splitting the process is not an option a cloud service (amazon, etc.) or your own cluster (spark/h2o) could be a way to go

Comment: What kind of operations do you want to do? Is it definitely necessary to read in all rows at once?

Comment: I could do the operations on each file at a time. It's the same operation every time: Separate 13 values that have been lumped together in one row by ;. E.g. +1;+2;0-1;none, etc.

Comment: Then that is by far the better approach - make a list of all the files, and use `lapply` to apply a function to each file.

Comment: maybe it's worth to do something like this with command line tools like `sed` or `awk`? Not sure about the speed differences?

Comment: @mhovd that makes sense. So apply to each file and rbind the result? Do I need to pre allocate the size of that dataframe as it's going to get copied each time it gets bigger. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I don't think that will be necessary. An alternative that might be feasible is not storing it in R at all, but for each read you write a line in a new .CSV file to store the results. I can type up an example answer in an hour.

Comment: @mhovd That would be amazing, thank you. The end result is a data.frame containing a down-sampled set of all the lines in the files so that I can do some visualisations in Shiny (but I guess that is a question for another day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot at answering your question.
While this may not be the most effective of efficient solution, it works. The biggest upside is that you don't need to store all the information at once, instead just appending the result to a file.

If this is not fast enough it is possible to use `parallell` to speed it up.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Make some example files
for (file_number in 1:1000) {
  df = data.frame(a = runif(10), b = runif(10))
  write_csv(x = df, path = paste0("example_",file_number,".csv"))
}

# Get the list of files, change getwd() to your directory,
list_of_files <- list.files(path = getwd(), full.names = TRUE)


# Define function to read, manipulate, and save result
read_man_save <- function(filename) {
  # Read file using data.table fread, which is faster than read_csv
  df = fread(file = filename)
  
  # Do the manipulation here, for example getting only the mean of A
  result = mean(df$a)
  
  # Append to a file
  write(result, file = "out.csv", append = TRUE)
}

# Use lapply to perform the function over the list of filenames
# The output (which is null) is stored in a junk object
junk <- lapply(list_of_files, read_man_save)

# The resulting "out.csv" now contains 1000 lines of the mean
```

Feel free to comment if you want any edits to better reflect your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I'm going to have to modify my workflow downstream I think for this as I'd been playing with a small test dataset which I was plotting interactively and dynamically using shiny. I think if I get al the means now that might be a way of down-sampling instead.

Comment: If you change up the list of files you can test this on smaller datasets, and also benchmark different approaches. When it comes to plotting everything you should ask yourself if you _need_ to plot 300GB of data. `disk.frame` (as suggeste by Wawv)or other utilities to accommodate large files is an option.

Comment: thank you. Yes I agree 100% I won't need all that data. I'm hoping that I can drastically down-sample it but I need to "see" what it looks like first. I.e. At least get some summary statistics but I haven't quite figured out how I will know how much I can throw away if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [disk.frame](https://diskframe.com/index.html) library, it is designed to allow manipulation of data larger than RAM.
You can then manipulate the data like you would in data.table or using dplyr verbs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this package. I think it might well solve a problem I will face down the line, at the moment I am at the stage where I can't import all of the files yet to make it one big 300GB data.table.

Comment: You can check the "Ingesting data" article : https://diskframe.com/articles/04-ingesting-data.html. There is an example about loading multiple csv files.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the package. I will use this too after I get this data in a manageable form.

Comment: I've just read that article a bit more carefully and it seems disk.frame can indeed ingest multiple csv files at one. I'll dig into this further